# Conditional `if` with command that doesn't respond in else

Tags: bash, shell, nc

I have the following command line, which should return the value `1` in case of, by means of `nc`, check communication with the IP and Port in question:

```
/bin/nc -z 10.102.10.22 10003 > /dev/null && if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi
```

The result is satisfactory and I get the value `1`. But when there is no communication with the Port or IP, the command is left "waiting", without getting value of any kind.

What would be the correct way to return the value `0` (the `else` statement) after a specific time has passed (e.g. 10 seconds).

The results of this command are monitored every short time to draw a communications graph, so it is interesting to know when it is `0`.

Comment: `timeout` exits with 124 if the command times out, so it should go the else branch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `&&` only applies the second part if the first part is true. So what you have is this

- `nc` succeeds, so run the `if it suceeded` (which it did) `echo 1`
- `nc` fails, so don't go past the `&&`

I think what you want is this

```
if nc -z 10.102.10.22 10003 > /dev/null; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi
```

Answer (score 7):

You seem to only run the `if` statement if `nc` completes successfully:

```
nc ... && if ...
```

This explains why `0` is never outputted. Since the `if` statement is not executed when `nc` fails, the `else` branch of the `if` statement is always unreachable.

Instead, use `nc` directly with `if`:

```bsh
if nc -z 10.102.10.22 10003 >/dev/null; then
    echo 1
else
    echo 0
fi
```

You could probably also write this particular statement using short-circuit logic:

```bsh
nc -z 10.102.10.22 10003 >/dev/null && echo 1 || echo 0
```

... but it's technically not the same thing as the `if` statement.  This last command would execute `echo 0` if *either of* `nc` or `echo 1` failed.

To get the `nc` command to exit after 10 seconds, use the GNU utility `timeout`:

```bsh
if timeout 10 nc -z 10.102.10.22 10003 >/dev/null; then
    echo 1
else
    echo 0
fi
```

---

The special variable `$?` is *very rarely used*.  You only need it in situations where you need to use the exit status of some command later than one or more further commands have executed.  For example, when returning an exit status from a shell function in some cases:

```bsh
myfunction () {
    grep -q 'pattern' file
    err=$?

    if [ "$err" -ne 0 ]; then
        echo failed >&2
    fi

    return "$err"
}
```

Here, both the `[ ... ]` test and the `echo` resets `$?`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other excellent answers, the result you want is also the arithmetic negation of the exit status:

```bsh
nc -z 10.102.10.22 10003 > /dev/null
echo $(( ! $? ))
```